# asp.net update panel not triggering

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I have a repeater that I have included within an update panel and I have buttons and a drop down list outside the repeater . I do not want the page to load every time I click a button or or change something in the drop down list.
I have my code below . I am having 2 problems with it which I am not able to resolve :

1) The control goes to the Page_Load event even when I use the update panel and triggers (btn15MIN_Click), so I guess there is something that I am doing wrong while writing the update panel code.

2) It takes a lot of time after changing the dropownlist value , to update the repeater.

```
<div class="MainGrid">
        <asp:Timer ID="RefreshTimer" runat="server" OnTick="RefreshTimer_Tick" Enabled="True">
        </asp:Timer>
        <div>
            <table width="100%" cellpadding="5">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblEndDate" runat="server" Text="LastUpdatedDate:" Font-Bold="true"
                                CssClass="label" ForeColor="Black"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblEndDateText" runat="server" CssClass="label" ForeColor="Black"></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblRefresh" runat="server" Text="Refresh Interval:" CssClass="label"
                                ForeColor="Black"></asp:Label>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btn15MIN" runat="server" OnClick="btn15MIN_Click" Text="15MIN">
                            </asp:LinkButton>&nbsp
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btn10MIN" runat="server" OnClick="btn10MIN_Click" Text="10MIN">
                            </asp:LinkButton>&nbsp
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btn5MIN" runat="server" OnClick="btn5MIN_Click" Text="5MIN">
                            </asp:LinkButton>&nbsp
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btn60SEC" runat="server" OnClick="btn60SEC_Click" Text="60SEC">
                            </asp:LinkButton>&nbsp
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btn30SEC" runat="server" OnClick="btn30SEC_Click" Text="30SEC">
                            </asp:LinkButton>&nbsp
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnOFF" runat="server" OnClick="btnOFF_Click" Text="btnOFF">
                            </asp:LinkButton>
                        </div>
                        <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblResultsDuration" runat="server" CssClass="label" ForeColor="Black">View Results since the last </asp:Label>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDuration" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlDuration_SelectedIndexChanged"
                                runat="server">
                                <asp:ListItem Text="2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="4" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="6" Value="6"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="8" Value="8"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="24" Value="24"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="48" Value="48"></asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblResultsDuration1" runat="server" CssClass="label">  Hours </asp:Label>
                        </asp:Panel>
                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="MainGridUpdatePanel" runat="server">
                            <Triggers>
                                <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btn15MIN"  />
                            </Triggers>
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:Panel ID="pnlMonitorSummary" runat="server">
                                    <ul id="monitorGallery" class="gallery ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix" style="margin-top: 5px;">
                                        <asp:Repeater ID="rptMonitorSummary" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptMonitorSummary_OnItemDataBound">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr">
                                                    <h5 class="ui-widget-header">
                                                        <%# Eval("Name").ToString().Length > 16 ? (Eval("Name") as string).Substring(0, 16) : Eval("Name")%>
                                                    </h5>
                                                    <div class="center">
                                                        <asp:Image Width="100px" ID="btnPerformanceImage" runat="server" Height="75px"></asp:Image>
                                                    </div>
                                                </li>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:Repeater>
                                    </ul>
                                </asp:Panel>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Can any one point me on the right direction on this

Comment: Every single post back in asp.net has to trigger the Page_Load event no matter what you use update panel or anything else, this is the Normal behavior of asp.net

Answer (score 1):

Every single post back in asp.net has to trigger the Page_Load event no matter what you use update panel or anything else, this is the Normal behavior of asp.net ,

and also try placing the Drop Down List inside the Update Panel so it will not perform a full postback when you change the selected Item:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblResultsDuration" runat="server" CssClass="label" ForeColor="Black">View Results since the last </asp:Label>
</asp:Panel>
     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="MainGridUpdatePanel" runat="server">
                            <Triggers>
                                <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btn15MIN"  />
                                <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlDuration"/>
                            </Triggers>

                            <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDuration" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlDuration_SelectedIndexChanged"
                                runat="server">
                                <asp:ListItem Text="2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="4" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="6" Value="6"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="8" Value="8"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="24" Value="24"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="48" Value="48"></asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblResultsDuration1" runat="server" CssClass="label">  Hours </asp:Label>


                                <asp:Panel ID="pnlMonitorSummary" runat="server">
                                    <ul id="monitorGallery" class="gallery ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix" style="margin-top: 5px;">
                                        <asp:Repeater ID="rptMonitorSummary" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptMonitorSummary_OnItemDataBound">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr">
                                                    <h5 class="ui-widget-header">
                                                        <%# Eval("Name").ToString().Length > 16 ? (Eval("Name") as string).Substring(0, 16) : Eval("Name")%>
                                                    </h5>
                                                    <div class="center">
                                                        <asp:Image Width="100px" ID="btnPerformanceImage" runat="server" Height="75px"></asp:Image>
                                                    </div>
                                                </li>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:Repeater>
                                    </ul>
                                </asp:Panel>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```